# Return code for wrong HTTP method in REST API?

Tags: api, rest, http

Our API user can get the *root* document (collection list) by sending `GET` request to root API address. If he sends `POST`, we should return something. The same question applies for other resource paths, like e.g. sending `PATCH` on query path etc. Not all methods have meaning on some paths.

As I see from HTTP RFCs is that we should return code `405`: **Method not allowed** and sending back the `Allowed` response header with list of allowed methods.

I see that e.g. GitHub API returns `404`: **Not found** in the case I explained above (sending `POST` to root).

What would be the proper response? `404` or `405`? I see `405` more developer-friendly, so is there any reason not to use it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The expected behavior in this case, as per the HTTP spec and by REST guidelines, would be to return `405 Method Not Allowed`. **The resource is there, since a GET works, so a `404 Not Found` would be confusing.**

I'm not familiar with the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) but in some cases I see that for `403 Forbidden` it also returns `404 Not Found`:

> Requests that require authentication will return 404 Not Found, instead of 403 Forbidden, in some places. This is to prevent the accidental leakage of private repositories to unauthorized users.

Maybe the behavior on the root address is part of a bigger mechanism that handles such cases generally, who knows. [Maybe you could ask](https://github.com/contact)?

Comment: A wrongful access-token definitely returns `403` "Bad credentials".