# How to handle calls to REST API endpoints with wrong HTTP verb?

Tags: java, rest, error-handling, jax-rs

Suppose I have REST endpoint which gives me properties of given media ID using `GET`. If user calls the endpoint with wrong HTTP verb, like `POST` or `DELETE`, I want to give descriptive error message saying "Method is not supported". I am using JAX-RS for REST mapping. JAX-RS just throws 404 with no descriptive error message.

What is the proper way of handling this scenario? Are there more descriptive ways of returning an error?

Comment: That's already what the 405 Not Allowed status does. Isn't that already being sent? You might be able to write an ExceptioMapper for NotAllowedException, if you want to send a message. I _think_ that is the exception thrown by RESTEasy. Not 100 percent sure. You can try it.

Comment: Oh and if you are getting a 404 instead of a 405, then the path to the resource doesn't exist. That is different than a 405. With 405, the path exists, but the method is not allowed. This is standard http stuff

Comment: I guess you can do that if you provide your own exception mappers similar to http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/error-handling-in-rest-api-with-jersey/ and figure out what exception your jax-rs throws when it doesn't find the verb, translate them accordingly.

Comment: I agree that it is standard HTTP stuff but I need to return error message saying 'Method is not supported'. I followed codingpedia article. It is really good to understand custom error handling. But now I am getting "No message body writer has been found for response class ErrorMessage." Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: This is related wrt HTTP standards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086582/return-code-for-wrong-http-method-in-rest-api